# Adding project to existing one

Tags: project, three20

I have a table view project with multiple controllers and another one that is a image gallery project and have  a Three20 project added to it. I found it in internet.
So i want when a table view cell is tapped  a image gallery opens. Both projects work fine when i test em separated . I tried dragging gallery project and adding it to my main project ,but  and then adding a headers to my project ,but the only thing i got are errors. Any ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell you anything, because you didn't mention detailed information of your works. At least, we must know that if you are using XCode 4, what kind of errors you have got! and so on...

Moreover, do you know how to link static library into XCode project. That's the way it should work!

Comment: Yes im using xcode 4 and i followed this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/1430/how-to-use-the-three20-photo-viewer ,but now i'm getting Three20/three20.h no such file i tried everything dragging and playng with target setting to link libraries but nothing

Comment: I posted a question before and found out the answer myself at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503567/error-building-adhoc-for-three20-integrated-app-on-xcode-4 Please take a look. The point I figured out is to make sure that the import library *.a are not in red color!